# Missing tools community version vs pro version Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used community version of Pycharm. If i will imshow image in matlibplot i will see this image.

[image]

In left bottom conner you can see pixs information (position and RBG color) Also handy tools such as paning the view, zoom box, and accessing axes settings directly from the plot.

But now i upgrade to profesional version of Pycharm. And the same code but this tools all gone. Can you help me plz how to get in?

[image]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh someone had the same problem overhere:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000736584-SciView-in-PyCharm-2017-3-reduces-functionality-of-Matplotlib

You have to manually write this:
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')